# Is there a list of <float> in ConTeXt?

Tags: floats, context

In LaTeX we have `\listoftables`, `\listoffigures`, and so on (at least thats the name as far as I remember).

Is there something to achive similar in ConTeXt?

My first thought was to define a register for tables and one for figures and one for each other type of float I need, and use it together with every single `\placetable`, `\placefigure`, `\placeSOMETHING`, and put a corresponding `\completeregister` in the appendeix, but to use the register with every `\place…` is easy to forget. Also the ordering would be wrong, since I want to order floats in the corresponding list by occurence, not by “name” or “label” or what ever.

Comment: Search the manual for ``\placelistof<<floats>>`` and ``\completelistof<<floats>>``.

Comment: OK, thats giving a list at least, but how can I modify the behaviour? So it gets a \chapter instead of a title? I will alter the question as soon as I have the time for it. \…listof… isn't documented very well, neither in contextref.pdf nor in the wiki :(

Comment: 1) Use ``\place...`` instead of ``\complete...`` and supply your own heading. 2) [``\setuplist``](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuplist) should get you started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Context, all commands derived from
[`\definefloat`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefloat)
receive their own list that behaves just like a normal list created
by [`\definelist`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definelist).
For example, for a floating object `foo` the corresponding setup
would be [`\setuplist[foo]`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuplist).
In order to output the list in your document, use `\placelist[foo]`
or `\placelistoffoo`.

```
\useMPlibrary [dum]
\definefloat [foo]
\setuplist [foo] [style=italic]
\starttext
  \placelistoffoo \page
  \dorecurse {10} {
    \startplacefoo [title=Some Foo Float]
      \externalfigure [dummy] [width=42mm]
    \stopplacefoo
  }
\stoptext
```

Another command, `\completelistoffoo`,
[auto-inserts](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/29661703c1b94925fe7bf61ee6afdc5f90dad285:/tex/context/base/strc-lst.mkvi#l276)
a `\title` heading with the list name first.

Since `\placefigure` and `\placetable` are derived using the same
mechanism, they also each come with a list predefined:

```
\setupexternalfigures [location=default]
\setuplist [figure] [style=slanted]
\starttext
  \placelist[figure]
  \dorecurse{4}{
    \startsection [title=Some Section]
      \input knuth \endgraf
      \startplacefigure [title=A Dutch Cow]
        \externalfigure [cow] [width=4.2cm]
      \stopplacefigure
      \input ward \endgraf
    \stopsection
  }
\stoptext
```

Comment: `\completelistoftables` does NOT insert a `\chapter` heading, it is inserting a `\title` heading, so it is not numbered and not in the TOC. *edit* Also I just realised, that the tables are numbered 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, etc in the text, but 1.I, 1.II, 2.I, etc in the list.

Comment: @NobbZ you’re correct, of course. Regarding the numbering, I cannot reproduce your result with either of my examples, anyways have a look at [conversion sets](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definestrcutureconversionset).